# How to set my target folder for an upload with a variable, in php?

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am new to php, hence cannot figure out my problem.
I have an HTML form that is connected to the mentioned php file. This form works fine. The problem is with the php file.
The HTML form is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And my php file called upload.php is:

```
    <?php
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $target_dir = "FILES OF:$uid";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Here, as you can see in the first lines of the php code, the target directory is set. But I want it to be with a variable called

```
    $uid
```

which is linked to the uid field in my database meaning username. What I mean to say is that I want it to upload files in the folder called "FILES OF:$uid".
I have these folders already created but want a way in which files will go directly to that folder. 
Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: If you want different folder for each user u must use database and login so when user login, you get user id and you can make dir based on that user id. With this approach you can't because `$_POST` variable reads name from a input of a form, and you don't have any username in there.

Answer (score 1):

hi i have link where you can check your code is correct or not if you don't want to check link then check following code.

[image upload to specific folder](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

following code is copy from given link

```
 <?php
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
    ?>


  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
```

Comment: You can't rely on mime type, its better to check for image extension.

Comment: no i can trust on mime type and it's work for me and i think you also use mine type. @Mario

Comment: Please read this before you trust :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349473/php-file-upload-mime-or-extension-based-verification

Comment: thank you, but I already have these codes. I wanted to know if there was a way in which I could set a variable instead of uploads/ in target directory.