# PHP - checking file type using exif_imagetype error

Tags: php

I am trying to check that an uploaded image is a PNG, JPG or GIF and not just check the file extension. I am trying the following:

```
$allowed_types = array (IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
$detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['file_to_upload']['tmp_name']);
    if ( !in_array($detectedType, $allowed_types) ) {
        die ( 'Please upload a pdf or an image ' );
    }


//code to handle image
```

However I am receiving an alert even if it is an image. Can anyone point me towards why?

Comment: Why downvote without any comment?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php check file extension in upload form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456113/php-check-file-extension-in-upload-form)

Comment: @shaggy i was trying to find out the extension from exif data, not by stating the names of the allowed extensions in an array so not duplicate

Comment: using mime type [is not accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349473/php-file-upload-mime-or-extension-based-verification), why do you want to use it?

Comment: @shaggy, to be suer that the files are actual image files and not a malicious file that has been given the extension .jpg, .png etc. How would you suggest the correct way if this is wrong?

Comment: Your code is the way how you get uploaded malicious file. Look at my previous comments, there is the right solution (both links).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should have been:

```
 $allowed_types = array (IMAGETYPE_PNG, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_GIF);
 $detectedType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    if ( !in_array($detectedType, $allowed_types) ) {
    die ( 'Please upload a pdf or an image ' );
  }
```